# Can't get homemade dropdown to display above the rest of my components

Tags: javascript, android, css, react-native

I am working on my own health and wellness app to help me learn React Native and decided to create my own search bar to search an API for medication names as the user types in the text input.  It all works fine, but when I go to use my homemade search bar the dropdown is not being displayed on top and is getting cut off by other components.  I have tried to add a zIndex and elevation to the dropdown but neither seem to work.  I also tried to add a lower zIndex's to the containers holding the search bar and still nothing :/ . Any help would be greatly appreciated!

JS file of search bar component: https://docdro.id/o7XImNR

I am also testing this app using an android emulator

[image of cut-off dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wum7W.png)

[image of what dropdown should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/at2Pu.png)

Comment: Can you share more context?

Comment: I am trying to be able to use the search bar anywhere in my code and having the dropdown display over the rest of the components.  Right now to get it to work I have to place it much further down in my code to display it on top of the rest as zIndex was not working.  I'll add an image of what it should look like :)